# Resolve ambiguous route issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, get, webapi

I wish to implement 2 get routes with definition as:

1. `GET /products` - gets all products.
2. `GET /products?name={name}` - finds all products matching the specified name.
   The code that I am using is:

`[HttpGet] public IActionResult GetProducts()`

and

`[HttpGet] public IActionResult GetProductByName([FromQuery(Name = "name")] string name)`

Can I achieve it?

Comment: You can have as a one method itself. When name is null or empty then return all products

Comment: Or change second one to something like `/products/{name}`

Comment: I am given a specification of these methods. I have to follow it.

Comment: @user1672994 Very interesting approach! Never thought about it! Sometimes the answer is simple. I like the way you think!

Answer (score 0):

Why not turn these into two separate endpoints one that is something like `[HttpGet("Products")]` and another endpoint that is `[HttpGet("Products/{name}]"`?

That way you can call your API like
`.../Products` and get all your Products back or `.../Products/Name` and get specific product information. You could also combine these into one endpoint `[HttpGet("Products/{name}]` and then return all your Products if `name` is null or empty.